# New compressor oil level

Tags: compressor

Reading from the service manual:

> INSTALLATION SERVICE POINT .>>A<< COMPRESSOR INSTALLATION 
>   If a new compressor is installed, first adjust the amount of oil according to the procedures described below, and then install the compressor.
>    1. Measure the amount [X cm3 (X floz)] of oil within the removed compressor.
>   2. Drain (from the new compressor) the amount [Y cm3 (Y floz)] of oil calculated according to the following formula, and then install the new compressor.

New compressor oil amount=140 cm3 (4.7floz)

140 cm3 − X cm3 = Y cm3 (4.7 floz − X floz = Y floz)

NOTE: Y cm3 (Y floz)indicates the amount of oil in the refrigerant line, the condenser, the evaporator, etc.

NOTE: When replacing the following parts at the same time as the compressor, subtract the rated oil amount of each part from Y cm3 (Y floz) and discharge from the new compressor.
 Quantity: 
 Evaporator: 60 cm3 (2.0 floz) 
 Condenser: 15 cm3 (0.5 floz) 
Suction hose: 10 cm3 (0.3 floz) 
 Receiver: 10 cm3 (0.3 floz)

Okay. Replacing a compressor. Pulled off the old compressor and only about 0.2 floz came out. I have also replaced the condenser, receiver, and expansion valve. So the amount X from the old compressor is 0.2 floz. That much I know. I did not add oil to any of the other parts thinking I could just add the oil to the compressor. I am so lost with these formulas. This is my second attempt at installing my AC system and I really want to get it right this time.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! When replacing the compressor, you have to clean your lines. Therefore there shouldn't be any oil left in it. If you don't clean the lines, condenser and all the other parts, you will void the warranty on your new compressor.

Comment: Does this calculation sound correct? 1.6 + .5 +.3 = 2.4 floz  in new compressor. 
4.7 total system capacity - (.3 suction hose +2 evaporator +.3 receiver + .5 condenser) = 1.6 actual for compressor alone. Then new compressor 1.6 + new consdenser .5 + new receiver .3 = 2.4.

Comment: Otherwise,  per their instructions, 4.7 - .2= 4.5 or y
Then subtracting from y, 4.5 - 0.5 for new condenser - 0.3 for new receiver = 3.7

Comment: Then 4.7 -3.7 =1 floz going into the new compressor and that doesn't sound right.

Comment: Best bet is to flush the entire system and put the full capacity of oil in, otherwise it is a guess as to what is in the system right now.

Comment: I'll do that next time. I put the part on with the amount of oil it came with (4.5 floz) and had a shop load up with 18 oz of freon. The temperature of the AC is slightly below where I want it to be.